# Can freeradius bypass authentication for one realm only?

Tags: authentication, freeradius2, freeradius

I have a question similar to [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/177821/how-to-configure-freeradius-to-accept-all-authentication-requests), but without the VLAN complications.  How can(?) I configure FreeRadius 1.x to allow any combination of username/password ***for one realm only?***

If FreeRadius 1.x does not provide this ability, does the 2.x line do so?  Does some other RADIUS server have this ability?  If so, I could configure this realm to proxy to the ..more tolerant... RADIUS server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about the RADIUS part, but rest should work.

From FreeRADIUS documentation, use [PAM](http://wiki.freeradius.org/index.php/FAQ#How_do_I_use_PAM_with_FreeRADIUS.3F) for this realm only, specify pam-auth type:

```
DEFAULT Huntgroup-Name ="somehunt", Auth-Type=PAM, Pam-Auth="radhunt", Simultaneous-Use=1
```

and then add `radhunt` file to `/etc/pam.d/` with this contents:

```
auth    required        pam_permit.so
account required        pam_permit.so
session required        pam_permit.so
```